# Batch file displaying Fragmentation - Formatting output

Tags: windows, batch-file

`defrag C: /A /V > %Temp%\defrag.txt
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"Total fragmented space" "%Temp%\defrag.txt" ') do SET "fragmentation=%%a"
ECHO %fragmentation%`

This code works fine but echos out the spaces in the file.
Here is the output:

`--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Total C Fragmentation:         Total fragmented space      = 3%`

Is there a way to get rid of those extra spaces? I have tried being more precise on what to search for by adding all the way up until the = sign but no luck.

I appreciate everyone help and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spaces as delimiter and retrieve the separated elements

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-8" %%a in (
    'findstr /C:"Total fragmented space" "%Temp%\defrag.txt" '
) do SET "fragmentation=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h"
```

Or you can directly use the equal sign as delimiter, get the value and later output what you need

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'findstr /C:"Total fragmented space" "%Temp%\defrag.txt" '
) do SET "fragmentation=%%a"
echo Total C Fragmentation: Total fragmented space =%fragmentation%
```

And in any of the two cases, the temporary file can be avoided as the `for` command can run the command and retrieve its output

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'defrag C: /A /V ^| findstr /C:"Total fragmented space" '
) do SET "fragmentation=%%a"
```

Comment: You are amazing! That you for your help!